# Android studio git message: following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge, but not showing which files

Tags: android, git, git-pull

I'm working on an android project in android studio and using VCS for working on git with the other members of the team.
Last time I tried to pull from origin, the following error came up:
"following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge", but it doesn't show me any file that caused the error.
I checked and every class and file in the project is added to git, so I don't know what the problem could be.
The change I've done was creating the folder "drawable" under the folder "res" and added an image that I use in the app; both was added to git. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you pull files from a remote branch your working directory should be clean.
Try `git status`(check if there are modified files in your working directory) -- it will show a list of files. Stash the changes/ reset them and try pulling again. This time it will work!

Comment: i saw the untracked files after i ran `git status` , so i ran `git add . ` and added all the files and then pulled, it worked! thanks mate!

Comment: Will adding all the untracked files after running the `git status` command creates any problems? Because there may be some files that are related to the version changes.